# How can i secure password or sensitive information when sending across the internet in .net c#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am validating a connection to Salesforce and other external apps.
I created a UI in AngularJS and MVC and whatever details the user types in the UI , I send that to my MVC controller (Post) and then send the information across as plain text to try and validate connection to the external app, which is not very secure.
I then save the details to a database , which are encrypted and if I want to re valiate , I decrypt the details and send again, once again not secure.

Surely there must be a class or some way in .Net that I can encrypt or hide these sensitive information across the internet
How can i do this , or is there some example that show how to do this that i can take a guide from ?

Comment: What's wrong with HTTPS?

Comment: Delegate authentication to some mutually trusted OIDC provider, don't get involved with user passwords unless you understand what you are doing.

Insist on HTTPS to encrypt data in transit.

Comment: I don't know what the "other external apps" are but I guarantee Salesforce is requiring HTTPS (TLS) which means you are not actually communicating in plain text

Comment: @Crowcoder I can confirm that Salesforce definitely uses HTTPS.

Comment: The app is Https , but I dont know what you mean by using https for validating with details. So basically when a user clicks on validate the data on the screen is sent to the my angular service and then to the mvc controller which is defined as [HttpPost] , so the details coming from my angular controller are plain text , thats ok , but I need to do a HttpPost attribute on my mvc controller , Because my db is in Azure if i need to save the details as well to the db its a HttpPost as well  , so im not entirely sure what you mena by using Https for these ActionResults ?

Comment: with Salesforce as an example to logon I have a partner wsdl and call  use service.login(Username, Password + Token); but these are not secure

Comment: "but these are not secure" - you mean they're on HTTP and not HTTPS?

Comment: yes , so when in transit i want to be able to secure them , is that possible ?

Comment: Uh, doesn't that entirely depend on how the other service needs to receive then? You should really ask them to switch to HTTPS so that you can access the service securely.

Comment: The bottom line here is that the standard way of securing credentials in transit is to encrypt the transport stream (see: HTTPS). It's good enough for all the banks, so it should be good enough for you.

Comment: ok will look at https , thanks

Comment: By the way, I wouldn't trust a service that accepts passwords over HTTP. That suggests they know nothing about security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any method of securing the data needs to be 2 sided
you can use encryption to obscure the data but the receiver has to be able to decrypt it. so if you have access to both ends of the system you can do that.

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream?view=net-6.0

if you don't you can't, however if you have access to both sides then why create a custom solution when you can use a prebuilt one such as https

incase you aren't aware how https works it takes a regular http packet and encrypts it into a new packet using the public key(encrypt only) of the receiving server, where the only thing that isn't encrypted is the address, once the receiving server receives the packet it uses its private key(decrypt and encrypt) to decrypt the packet so it can read the headers, body, etc and then handles the packet like a normal http request. this means just by using the https protocol you have secured the entire communication from sender to receiver with out actually changing the way anything works at either end